# in Lua, should I assign all table element to nil when it's not used?

Tags: memory-leaks, lua, garbage-collection, lua-table

For example, I have created a table this way

```
myTable = {}
for n=1,5
    local item = {
        name = "item"..n,
        id = n,
    }
    myTable[n] = item
end
```

When this table is no longer used, in order to release this table for the garbage collector,

do I need to loop through the table to assign each element to nil?

```
for n=1,5
    myTable[n] = nil
end
```

or all I just need to do is to assign the table to nil?

```
myTable = nil
```

On addition to the above, what if the table element has some property that is assigned to some other table, do I need to nil them individually too?

```
for n=1,5
    myTable[n].someTable = nil
    myTable[n] = nil
end
myTable = nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply assign `myTable = nil` is fine. You can test it like this, using the `__gc` metamethod:

```
myTable = {}
for n=1,5 do
    local item = {
        name = "item"..n,
        id = n,
    }
    setmetatable(item, {__gc = function (self) print("item " .. n .." collected") end})
    myTable[n] = item
end

myTable = nil

collectgarbage()
```

Output:

```
item 5 collected
item 4 collected
item 3 collected
item 2 collected
item 1 collected
```

This means all the `item` tables are collected by the garbage collector.

Comment: How about my last question: if the table item has a property assigned to other table, do I need to nil it too? or still, just `myTable = nil` will do?

Comment: @Joe The same, `myTable = nil` will do. The Lua garbage collector knows the other table is not referenced in this table any more, and would finally collect it when it's not referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

All is about references. Even if you have setted to nil a variable that references a table if there is another reference to the table the Garbage Collector doesn't free memory. Because table is still "in use".

Ex:

```
myTable = {}
myOtherTable = myTable
for n=1,5 do
    local item = {
        name = "item"..n,
        id = n,
    }
    myTable[n] = item
end

print(myTable)
myTable=nil
print(myTable)
print(myOtherTable)

--OUTPUT
--table: 0x8ebb40
--nil
--table: 0x8ebb40
```

If a table is referenced anywhere (even inside another table) it isn't freed.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but it's kind of different than my question.

Comment: It was just for rethinking the question. Short: If no element on the table or the table itself haven't references the table will be collected if you nil it as Yu Hao showed.